# How could I pass the type using Variables to the generic method?

Tags: c#, types, generics

I have a generic method in c#:

```
public IList<T> getList<T>();
```

When I call it as the way below?

```
...
Type T1=metadata.ModelType;
getList<T1>();
```

...

I got error in compiling.

How could I do for it?
I really need to pass the type as Variables to the generic method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oded pointed out, you cannot do this the way you tried, since `<T>` does not accept types. You can, however, achieve what you want using reflection:

```
Type T1=metadata.ModelType;

MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod("getList");
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { T1 });

genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

If `getList` is a static method, or in another class, you need to replace `GetType()` by `typeof(...)` with ... being the name of the class.

Answer (score 3):

The generic parameter is a *type* parameter:

```
getList<string>(); // Return a list of strings
getList<int>(); // Return a list of integers
getList<MyClass>(); // Return a list of MyClass
```

You are not calling it with a *type* but with an object.

Comment: Oded, I disagree, it is not called it with an object either. It's only callable when you resolve the generic type first.

Comment: @Enigmativity: what do you mean by that? What do you mean by “resolve”? OP *is* trying to pass an object as a type so you’re wrong.

Comment: @Oded,I don't know the real type before running time, so this is not the way I expected.

Comment: @"Konrad Rudolph" - He's not passing "an object as a type", he's trying to pass "a type as an object". Normally compile-time type resolution is required. Only using reflection can the type be passed as an object at run-time. I don't know what passing an object as a type would actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can't : in your sample, T1 is an instance of the System.Type class and not an actual type like IList for example